# Do wall ac/heater units bring in fresh air?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, air-quality, air

I live in an apartment with a combined wall AC/heater unit, like the type that you often find in hotels.  Does this bring in fresh air when operating, or does it just recirculate the air inside the room?  Does it operate differently depending on whether it is in heating, cooling, or fan-only mode?  I'd like to be able to keep the fan on in the spring and fall instead of opening the window because a neighbor smokes in the courtyard, but I want to be sure to get fresh air in here.  Specifically, the one in my apartment is an Amana PTH153B50AM.

https://www.ajmadison.com/cgi-bin/ajmadison/PTH153B50AM.html

[image]

Comment: In my experience it's exceedingly rare for one of these units to bring fresh air in. Unless it contains the extra heat exchange mechanism, bringing fresh air in works against the function the unit is trying to perform.

Comment: @brhans I agree, though looking at a functional diagram would give a definitive answer. My hunch is that these units are in walls in order to be able to send waste heat (in AC mode) outside.

Comment: Some do, some don't.

Answer (score 2):

The ones I have worked on only bring in fresh air if it has a lever that opens a small vent that allows fresh air to be pulled in.
on the low or intake side of the fan when the door is open it sucks a small amount in,
other than that they are basically sealed separating inside from outside and do not allow outside air in.